# Remove variable parts of a string that start and end the same

Tags: python, string, python-2.x

I have a string as the following:

```
'1:CH,AG,ME,GS,AP,CH,HE,AC,AC,AG,CA,HE,AT,AT,AC,AT,OG,NE,AG,AC,CS,OD\n&:TA,EB,PA,AC,BR,TH,PO,AC,2I,AC,TH,PE,TH,AZ,AZ,ZE,CS,OD,CH,EO,ZE,OG\n&:TH,ZE,ZE,HE,HE,HP,HP,OG,HP,ZE\n2:ZE,FD,FD,AG,EO,OG,AG,NE,RU,GS,HP,ZE,ZE,HM,HM,PC,PC,AS,AS,TY,TY,AG\n&:AG,GS,NO,EU,ZF,HE,AT,AT,OD,OD,EB,OD,GS,TR,OD,AC,TR,GS,OD,TR,OD,AT,GS\n&:CA,GS,NE,GS,AG,PS,HL,AG,NE,ID,AJ,AX,DI,OD,ME,AT,GS,MU,HO,PB,LT,9Z,PT,9Y\n&:9W,9X,AR,9V,9U,9T,AX,9S,9R,AT,AJ,DI,ST,EA,AG,ME,NE,MU,9Q,9P,9O,9N,9M,9L\n&:9K,ID,MG,OD,FY,AU,AU,HR,HR,9J,TL,9I,9H,9G,9F,AC,BR,AC,9E,9D,9C,9B,99\n'
```

As you can see, I would like to get the '\n(number or & here):' replaced by ','
Since they all start with '\n' and end with ':' I believe that there should be a way to replace them all at once.

The output would be as the sort:

```
'CH,AG,ME,GS,AP,CH,HE,AC,AC,AG,CA,HE,AT,AT,AC,AT,OG,NE,AG,AC,CS,OD,TA,EB,PA,AC,BR,TH,PO,AC,2I,AC,TH,PE,TH,AZ,AZ,ZE,CS,OD,CH,EO,ZE,OG,TH,ZE,ZE,HE,HE,HP,HP,OG,HP,ZE,ZE,FD,FD,AG,EO,OG,AG,NE,RU,GS,HP,ZE,ZE,HM,HM,PC,PC,AS,AS,TY,TY,AG,AG,GS,NO,EU,ZF,HE,AT,AT,OD,OD,EB,OD,GS,TR,OD,AC,TR,GS,OD,TR,OD,AT,GS,CA,GS,NE,GS,AG,PS,HL,AG,NE,ID,AJ,AX,DI,OD,ME,AT,GS,MU,HO,PB,LT,9Z,PT,9Y,9W,9X,AR,9V,9U,9T,AX,9S,9R,AT,AJ,DI,ST,EA,AG,ME,NE,MU,9Q,9P,9O,9N,9M,9L,9K,ID,MG,OD,FY,AU,AU,HR,HR,9J,TL,9I,9H,9G,9F,AC,BR,AC,9E,9D,9C,9B,99'
```

What could work was making a for lop for numbers and &.

```
string.replace('\n&:',',')
for i in range(1,20): 
    string.replace('\ni:',',')
```

But I believe there must be a better way.

Comment: Please provide example of the output you expect. Also try to provide a more readable input if possible. Finally, have you tried anything from which we can help you?

Comment: can you show expected output?

Comment: Sorry about that, i don't know why it wasn't taken as code.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon I added a way that can technically solve the problem but the point is not solve if for this string specifically but for any string that you would like to.

Comment: @AntonioLópezRuiz So what you want to do is remove \n&: ?

Comment: replace it by ',' but not only that one, it could be '\n2:' or '\n3:' or anything that starts with '\n' and ends with ':'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to get the job done:

Input:

```
import re
text = '1:CH,AG,ME,GS,AP,CH,HE,AC,AC,AG,CA,HE,AT,AT,AC,AT,OG,NE,AG,AC,CS,OD\n&:TA,EB,PA,AC,BR,TH,PO,AC,2I,AC,TH,PE,TH,AZ,AZ,ZE,CS,OD,CH,EO,ZE,OG\n&:TH,ZE,ZE,HE,HE,HP,HP,OG,HP,ZE\n2:ZE,FD,FD,AG,EO,OG,AG,NE,RU,GS,HP,ZE,ZE,HM,HM,PC,PC,AS,AS,TY,TY,AG\n&:AG,GS,NO,EU,ZF,HE,AT,AT,OD,OD,EB,OD,GS,TR,OD,AC,TR,GS,OD,TR,OD,AT,GS\n&:CA,GS,NE,GS,AG,PS,HL,AG,NE,ID,AJ,AX,DI,OD,ME,AT,GS,MU,HO,PB,LT,9Z,PT,9Y\n&:9W,9X,AR,9V,9U,9T,AX,9S,9R,AT,AJ,DI,ST,EA,AG,ME,NE,MU,9Q,9P,9O,9N,9M,9L\n&:9K,ID,MG,OD,FY,AU,AU,HR,HR,9J,TL,9I,9H,9G,9F,AC,BR,AC,9E,9D,9C,9B,99\n'
text = re.sub(r'\n&*(\d*:)*',',', text[2:]).rstrip(',')
```

Output:

```
'CH,AG,ME,GS,AP,CH,HE,AC,AC,AG,CA,HE,AT,AT,AC,AT,OG,NE,AG,AC,CS,OD,TA,EB,PA,AC,BR,TH,PO,AC,2I,AC,TH,PE,TH,AZ,AZ,ZE,CS,OD,CH,EO,ZE,OG,TH,ZE,ZE,HE,HE,HP,HP,OG,HP,ZE,ZE,FD,FD,AG,EO,OG,AG,NE,RU,GS,HP,ZE,ZE,HM,HM,PC,PC,AS,AS,TY,TY,AG,AG,GS,NO,EU,ZF,HE,AT,AT,OD,OD,EB,OD,GS,TR,OD,AC,TR,GS,OD,TR,OD,AT,GS,CA,GS,NE,GS,AG,PS,HL,AG,NE,ID,AJ,AX,DI,OD,ME,AT,GS,MU,HO,PB,LT,9Z,PT,9Y,9W,9X,AR,9V,9U,9T,AX,9S,9R,AT,AJ,DI,ST,EA,AG,ME,NE,MU,9Q,9P,9O,9N,9M,9L,9K,ID,MG,OD,FY,AU,AU,HR,HR,9J,TL,9I,9H,9G,9F,AC,BR,AC,9E,9D,9C,9B,99'
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression replace:

```
s = '1:CH,AG,ME,GS,AP,CH,HE,AC,AC,AG,CA,HE,AT,AT,AC,AT,OG,NE,AG,AC,CS,OD\n&:TA,EB,PA,AC,BR,TH,PO,AC,2I,AC,TH,PE,TH,AZ,AZ,ZE,CS,OD,CH,EO,ZE,OG\n&:TH,ZE,ZE,HE,HE,HP,HP,OG,HP,ZE\n2:ZE,FD,FD,AG,EO,OG,AG,NE,RU,GS,HP,ZE,ZE,HM,HM,PC,PC,AS,AS,TY,TY,AG\n&:AG,GS,NO,EU,ZF,HE,AT,AT,OD,OD,EB,OD,GS,TR,OD,AC,TR,GS,OD,TR,OD,AT,GS\n&:CA,GS,NE,GS,AG,PS,HL,AG,NE,ID,AJ,AX,DI,OD,ME,AT,GS,MU,HO,PB,LT,9Z,PT,9Y\n&:9W,9X,AR,9V,9U,9T,AX,9S,9R,AT,AJ,DI,ST,EA,AG,ME,NE,MU,9Q,9P,9O,9N,9M,9L\n&:9K,ID,MG,OD,FY,AU,AU,HR,HR,9J,TL,9I,9H,9G,9F,AC,BR,AC,9E,9D,9C,9B,99\n'
s = re.sub(r"(\n\d*?:)|(\n&:)", ",", s).strip()  # replaces the middle bits with commas and strips trailing \n
s = re.sub(r"^(\d*?:)|(&:)", "", s)              # removes the initial 1: or similar
```